# Mysql : Throw an exception inside procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, exception

I have this code below that should throw an exception if amount is negative :

```
create procedure depositMoney(
        IN acc integer,
        IN amoun integer
    )
    BEGIN
        DECLARE negative CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
        IF amoun < 0 THEN SIGNAL negative;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO account(balance) VALUES amoun where account.number = acc;
    END;
```

but when i execute i have an #1064 error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
```

Could you help me ?

Comment: Is the line of the declare statement the source of the error?

Comment: You must close the `IF` (`END IF`) and remember to use `DELIMITER`.

Comment: yes Shadow it's the line. wchiquito even when i close the If, i get the same error

Comment: probably need parenthesis in insert statement ... VALUES (amoun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the syntax of the INSERT.

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `depositMoney`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `depositMoney` (
  IN `acc` INTEGER,
  IN `amoun` INTEGER
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE `negative` CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
  IF `amoun` < 0 THEN
    SIGNAL `negative`
    SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred';
  END IF;
  /*
  Check the syntax of the INSERT.
  INSERT INTO account(balance) VALUES amoun where account.number = acc;
  */
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

MySQL 5.5 or higher.

Test:

```sql
mysql> CALL `depositMoney`(NULL, -1);
ERROR 1644 (45000): An error occurred
```

Comment: it worked ! thanks, though i still don't know what was the problem ;)